# spinner gravity

Tags: java, android, layout

spinner gravity only seems to work in the horizontal dimension.  I would like the displayed text to on the top vertically and centered horizontally.  Is this possible?
I use an xml spinner normal style like this:

```
<TextView  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" 
    android:textColor="#ffffff" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up, hope i helps

```
     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/m1_ss_spinner" 
        android:background="@drawable/btn_default_normal_invisible" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_gravity="top" 
        android:layout_below="@id/m1_ss_head" 
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

you have `wrap_content` for height, so the view shrinks around the text and there is no space for the text to be positioned on the top of the view. `android:gravity` works only if there is enough space for the content within the activity. `center_horizontal` works because you have set fill_parent for the width and I assume the view takes all of the screens width, thus allowing the contents to be centered.

Try rearranging your layout so that there is more space for the view in terms of height.

cheers!